# Determining when you've encountered a bug or improvement request: FBX export times

Tags: modifiers, export, .fbx

I posted about experiencing long .FBX export times in a previous post:
[FBX export time takes 5 times longer when using mask modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102717/fbx-export-time-takes-5-times-longer-when-using-mask-modifier)

To summarize again:

1. When disabling the mask modifier, the export time is 30 seconds
2. When applying the modifier prior to export, the export time is 30
   seconds (same as #1)
3. When enabling and not manually applying the modifier prior to export, and selecting "Apply Modifiers" on the FBX export settings, the export time is 2.5 minutes

It doesn't make a whole lot of sense that there would be a noticeable difference between #2 and #3 export times.
This is an on-going issue that is plaguing me with numerous models, and only gets worse as the number of modifiers are added.
Could anyone tell me whether is is a bug or something that could be addressed as some type of an improvement that could be suggested?

I'm at the point where when using method #3 it is taking 10 minutes to generate the .FBX, where #2 is taking 30 seconds.

Comment: I don't really see how this is different from the other question you asked. I think you should have just edited it and added more details.

Comment: What a joke and waste of time this site has become. Can I request that my account be closed? Or can someone just go ahead and close it.

Comment: @TTTTTTa yah if you *really* want you account deleted you can do that. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account